# Set each option value dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this on my page

```
<script id="score" type="text/template">
    <select name="scoreSelector">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Your Score</option>
        <option id="val1" value="0">Quarter</option>
        <option id="val2" value="0">Half</option>
        <option id="val3" value="0">Three Quarter</option>
    </select>
</script>
```

How do I set each option value?

E.g.

```
<script>
    $('select[name=scoreSelector]').val('0.25');
</script>
```

Since the above select is inside `<script id="score" type="text/template">`, how do I set values dynamically using jQuery?

Comment: Where are the values to set dynamically? And you can use `$('[name="scoreSelector"]' option[id]').each(function() { $(this).val('something'); });`

Comment: @Tushar I need to set different values for each option. E.g.: `val1` = 0.25 , `val2` = 0.5 , `val3` = 0.75

Comment: @Becky, `$.each` has argument called as `index`. Something like `+=` will help!

Comment: @Tushar: Could you show how to set different values?  Dosen't the above set the same value to all options? I'm looking to set 3 different values for each option

Comment: will all values be of .25 gap?

Comment: Try this: `var CONST = 0.25,
  init = 0;
$('[name="scoreSelector"] option[id]').each(function() {
  this.value = init += CONST;
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo of  @RayonDabre's solution:

```js
var vals = [null, 1 / 4, 1 / 2, 3 / 4];
$('select[name="scoreSelector"] option').each(function(i, o) {
  $(o).val(vals[i]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="scoreSelector">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Your Score</option>
  <option id="val1" value="0">Quarter</option>
  <option id="val2" value="0">Half</option>
  <option id="val3" value="0">Three Quarter</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var val = .25;

$('#score option[id]').attr('value', function () {
  var thisVal = val;
  val = val + .25
  return thisVal;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1) for the first option i.e select score should have no value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var val = 0;
      $('select[name = "scoreSelector"] option').each(function(i) {
        if (i != 0) { 
          $(this).val(val += .25);
        }
      });
    });
```

2) if first option should have value of zero then.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          var val = 0;
          $('select[name = "scoreSelector"] option').each(function(i) {

              $(this).val(val);
              val += .25;

      });
 });
```

here is the working fiddle
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9uo6rv4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Number instead of array and increment it when setting the value.

Instead of iterating over all the `<option>`s, use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function) with function callback.

```js
var val = 0, // For first option
  increment = 0.25;

$('select[name="scoreSelector"] option[id]').val(function() {
  return val += increment; // Increment and return
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="scoreSelector">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Your Score</option>
  <option id="val1" value="0">Quarter</option>
  <option id="val2" value="0">Half</option>
  <option id="val3" value="0">Three Quarter</option>
</select>
```

Comment: By using this, you're not using any array. More flexible, work with any number of `<option>`s.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ID you assigned to each option element.

```
$('#val1').val(.25);
$('#val2').val(.5);
$('#val3').val(.75);
```

Comment: What if there are `n` options ?

Comment: The OP didn't ask for `n` options.  I answered the question asked.  Don't downvote simply because it's not scalable.  The OP didn't ask for a scalable answer.

Comment: Well in that case there are my dups for this question(_How to set value of input element[JQuery]_)

Comment: Then mark it as a duplicate and link the correct answer?

Comment: I downvoted this because, in my opinion, while this *technically* answers the question, it is a poor solution and should not be used as other far superior solutions exist. Keep in mind that questions on SO often include a *minimal and verifiable* example of the problem. The OP might have dozens of options in their production code (even if the OP doesnt explicitly say so).

Comment: Far superior solutions is subjective.  For the question given, my 3 lines of code is actually far more efficient than any of the looping / `.each()` solutions given, but you're free to downvote whatever you like.

Comment: Also, I firmly believe that every time incremental ids are used in HTML, somewhere in the world, a cute little fuzzy kitten is drowned. And such practices should be vehemently discouraged. Save the kittens!  ;)

Comment: Again, that's your opinion, which is subjective, but I didn't mean to start a long thread in the comments.  My only request is next time you downvote something please include a comment as to why you think it's a poor answer.